# Endless Load on Scroll or how to no trigger an event numerous times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented a load function which is getting triggered whenever one reaches end of the page. It's working basicly, but the event gets triggered numerous times, whenever I scroll down. is there a better way to implement this idea or a way to *not* trigger this event numerous times?

Here's what I did:

```
var loading = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if((($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height())+250)>=$(document).height()){
        if(loading == false){
            loading = true;
            $.get("test", function(data){
             $("div.article:last").after(data);
});
            loading = false;

        }
    }
});
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loaded_max').val(500);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript is rendered form top to bottom. If you put `loading = false` inside the `callback of your $.get` function, it won't attempt to load or fire until the get request is completed. I think this is the functionality you desire. So....long story short, put `loading === false` after `$('div.article:last').after(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
$.get("test", function(data){
    $("div.article:last").after(data);
});
loading = false;
```

The `loading=false;` is outside your `$.get` callback function. The `$.get` is a async function which means. `loading=false;`is executed directly after your `$.get` and not when your Ajax call is ready.

If you put your `loading=false;` inside your `$.get` callback. You won't have multiple requestst at the same time.

Solution to get only 1 request at a time:

```
$.get("test", function(data){
    $("div.article:last").after(data);
    loading = false;
});
```

Also I would start loading the next part of the page like 400px before people reach the bottom. So they can keep on scrolling and don't have to wait for your request to be ready. I'ts more smooth that way.